# Force Google Chrome to visit a website with IPv4 (instead of IPv6), possible?

Tags: google-chrome, ip, ipv6, ipv4

Is there any way to force Chrome to visit a certain website with IPv4 only and not use the IPv6 address?

I know there is a way which works for Firefox, as in going to "**about:config**" then search for `network.dns.ipv4OnlyDomains` and there you can enter the websites/domains you want to force Firefox to visit by using IPv4 only.

So, is there a way to achieve this in Chrome as well? Reason for this is, is that I have to visit a secured website, however I am getting tired changing the .htaccess all the time, because my IPv6 address changes daily (my IPv4 address stays the same/static).

Of course I can (and am) using Firefox as well, but I need two different browser connections.

So hopefully someone knows a way in Chrome?

Comment: Do you mean the IPv6 _prefix_ is changed by your ISP (the first half), or do you mean only the interface identifier (second half of the address) keeps changing? The latter can be made static easily, as long as the ISP-provided prefix stays the same.

Comment: Well my IPv6-addresses changes, so when I visit a personal company website, I have to change the IPv6 address in the .htaccess all the time. Therefor I want to disable IPv6 access to that website. Just like I did it in Firefox, but I am guessing that this is not possible and/or my question is not correctly explained (sorry for that).

Comment: I was asking about _which part_ of your IPv6 address changes...

Comment: The last 4 parts/sections. The first 3 stays the same, as far as I can tell atm.

Comment: So the ISP gives you a static prefix, and you could solve your problem by configuring your computer to stop changing its suffix (the last 4 parts), i.e. disabling the "Privacy Extensions" feature – as an alternative to needing to disable IPv6 outright.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot seem to find this option in Chrome...

Comment: @user1686 bunch of non-related questions to the topic

Comment: Is this even chrome's decision to make? Doesn't it request a socket from the OS and there the IP gets assigned? Try accessing the website with curl, firefox or any other browser do these use IPv4?

Comment: @Cowboy_Patrick you can configure Curl and Firefox to use v4

Answer (score 1):

Use nslookup, such as `nslookup MySite.com`.
When used as `nslookup google.com`, the reply is:

```
Name:       google.com
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:4009:808::200e
            142.250.190.14
```

So enter `https://142.250.190.14` instead of `https://google.com` into your Chrome browser.

Comment: But then the certificate fails.